# What are Arvak's stats compared to Shadowmere's?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to know which one to use. I know shadowmere is very powerful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Shadowmere](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere) is the superior of the two with much higher level (50), health (1637) and stamina (198) compared to [Arvak's](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arvak) level (4), health (289) and stamina (106). Shadowmere also has additional health regeneration.

[image]